# SQL expression to select members in crystal reports

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a database that among other things, has a view that lists various fields pertaining to "clients", and another view that lists various fields pertaining to "patients".  In the software application I am using, I am passed the value of an individual patient id.  I need to create an SQL expression that would return the client ID that the patient "belongs to" so that I can then create a list of all the patients that belong to that client.
For  example:

```
 Client 1
    patient A
    patient B
    patient C
Client 2
    patient D
    patient E
    patient F
```

If I am passed the value for patient C, I need to generate this list in Crystal Reports:

```
   Patient A
   Patient B
   Patient C
```

Thanks,  I'm not sure where to even start with this one.

Comment: you can do this in crystal reports... no need to manipulate in queries.. have you done joining in crystal?

Comment: I have not done joins in crystal reports.  Do you use the command function?

Comment: Sql command is one way... if you are well versed with queries write sql command after making connection...if not just drag and drop views and join them in database expert

Comment: I tried the various types of joins in the database expert but I was unsuccessful in getting a useful result. I have one view of "client" fields and another of "patients". There should be a one- to- one relationship between the views. I have an inner join link.  I end up getting all patients, not just the patient I want.

Comment: You can filter required patient in crystal report

Comment: I made good progress on this but I still don't have it yet. I created the following command:

Comment: Where is the command

Comment: Sorry:Select "EntPatients"."IDPatient" 
From "RAH"."dbo"."Entpatients"
Where "EntPatients"."IDClient" in (Select "EntPatients"."IDClient" from "RAH"."dbo"."EntPatients" where "EntPatients"."IDPatient"={?<PatientID>})

Comment: This works when I run it as a preview in Crystal reports but it does not work when I run it in my software program that uses Crystal to generate a report.  It appears the parameter is not getting passed to the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Select p.patientid 
from patients p 
where p.clientid in 
  (select c.clientid 
  from clients c 
  where c.patientsid = ?yourpatientid)

Comment: So using the actual view and field names from my database this is what I want?

Select "EntPatients"."IDPatient" From Entpatients Where "EntPatients"."ClientID" in (Select "EntPatients"."ClientID" from EntPatients where "EntPatients"."IDPatient"= <?PatientID>)

I am creating this as an SQL expression; Can I put this in the record selection formula section? That would seem to be the only way to get my parameter into the formula. When writing the syntax for the "From" statement, the name of the view (Entpatients) isn't accepted by Crystal the way I have it written above.